# Angular 2 Http Get Request header issue

Tags: http, angular, get, header, cors

My Angular 2 Service is calling and external api , but i am getting a error in the browser console. I tried adding headers to the Get method but still the error persists.

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class CompetitionService{

     constructor(private http:Http){

     }

    getCompetitions(){
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        return this.http.get('http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions',{headers:headers}).map(response => response.json())
    }
}
```

console log Before Header

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

After Header
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: the `Access-Control` headers need to be set at the server side not client.. this is a cors issue

Comment: Any way we can get around it?

Comment: depends on what type of backend you are using.. you will have to set these headers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is CORS issue in browser and football-data api

http://api.football-data.org/docs/v1/index.html#_cors_handling

> However, if you implement requests directly from Javascript, you need
>   to add your X-Auth-Token correctly so the API gives you permission to
>   do that

so to call api from your app, you need add header:

```
getCompetitions(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    let token = 'your token';
    headers.append('X-Auth-Token', token);
    return this.http.get('http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions',{headers:headers}).map(response => response.json())
}
```

Comment: Doesn't  work, same error after trying your suggestion